# How can I create a table type with multiple columns and use it in a stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I created a table type to use it as input in a stored procedure, so that the procedure can receive multiple customer IDs at once. 
But now I also need to use other data related to the customers and I was wondering how I can use the type I created with multiple custom columns, and not only Customer ID.

This is how it is now:

```
CREATE TYPE T_CUSTOMERS IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_SAMPLE (
    CUSTOMERS_LIST IN T_CUSTOMERS,
    C1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
...
END;
```

Comment: create a record type, declare as many fields in it as you like.

Comment: @OldProgrammer by doing so, will I be able to pass multiple rows at once to the procedure?

Comment: You need to create 2 types: record and table of 1st type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `OBJECT` type and then create the table type containing the newly created objects.

```
CREATE TYPE T_CUSTOMERS_OBJ AS OBJECT (
    CUSTOMER_ID     NUMBER,
    CUSTOMER_NAME   VARCHAR2(300)
);
/

CREATE TYPE T_CUSTOMERS IS
    TABLE OF T_CUSTOMERS_OBJ;
/
```

Then you can use the `T_CUSTOMERS` type in your procedure.